# Prove $p(\alpha_n x_n)\to 0$ provided $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges and $p(x_n)\to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a vector space. A map $p : E \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies :

1. $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$ ;
2. For a fixed $x\in E$, $\lambda \mapsto p(\lambda x)$ is continuous ;
3. For all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, if $p(x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$, then $p(\lambda x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Prove that

- $p(\mathbf{0})=0$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero vector in $E$ ;
- If $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb{R}$ converges, and $p(x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $p(\alpha_n x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

I can answer the first question, but the second one is confused to me. Maybe there are some conditions lost, I have no idea. Looking forward to good ideas, thank you for your help!

Comment: I changed the formatting a bit so that it reads a bit better. Hope this is to your liking.

Comment: The first claim is false. Take the function $p :\equiv 1$. Note that it satisfies all the conditions and $p(\textbf{0}) \neq 0$.